# Implementing FBA & Windows auth with user profiles in 2013

Tags: 2013, user-profile, active-directory, forms-authentication

Has anyone successfully implemented a multi auth SP2013 farm but managed to retain a single source user profile?

my client has a bad AD Domain set up and so as a result users are going to be prompted to use their central Domain account to log in or alternatively they can use FBA (This is a client requirement not a recommendation) The problem I have with this is that now I am struggling to understand how I can fully utilise users profiles in SP2013 consistently.

As far as I can see each user could end up with 2 profiles if they decide to use windows auth one day and FBA the next, is there some way I can tie all users down to one profile, this would obviously assume the FBA name or some other property matches a windows auth property in AD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try implementing FBA with AD as the LDAP source for your authentication. This may solve the two identities issue. Check Mirjam's post on the topic: http://sharepointchick.com/archive/0001/01/01/configuring-claims-and-forms-based-authentication-for-use-with-an.aspx

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I think this still causes the issue as the user can use FBA or Windows Auth still and thus will get to either thier FBA(claims) account or Windows Auth(claims) account.

Comment: I see, I missed the word "alternatively". Yes this is a bad practice. Another, though bloated solution may be to write your own Authentication Provider that draws from each source and disambiguates the User ID. Not trivial, but good for billing a client who is making poor choices.

Comment: Thankfully after some lengthy discussion it was decided to stick with windows authentication, thanks for the help.